# How to go from long to wide with stated preference data in R

Tags: r, reshape

I hope this is not a cross-posting. I have been trying to understand from the available links on stackoverflow how to perform a change in the data from long to wide. I think I am almost there but there is still a lot missing.

[image]

I have stated prefence data on the choice between an electric and a gasoline car. Some variables are related to cars in general, such as PREZZO, whilst some other are specific to electric cars, such as AUTONOMIA_EV and others to internal combustion engine cars, such as AUTONOMIA ICEV.

Each respondent is identified by a number in the column INTERTOT. The first respondent has number 111. There are 20 rows corresponding to this individual because he faces 10 choices amongst two cars, one electric and one gasoline. In the column SCELTAEFF2 a value equal to 1 indicates the choice performed by the individual. Such a value has to be compared to correspoding one reported in column EV, where a value of 1 indicates that the option in that line is an electric vehicle.

Therefore, for example, if you look at line 4, which concerns the second choice confronted by the first individual, the column SCELTAEFF2 takes a value of 1 and the corresponding row on the column EV is 1 as well. This means that the respondent, for the second proposed alternatives, choose the electric vehicle. If you look, insted, at line 8, which concerns the fourth choice, the individual choose a gasoline car. This is the case because the column SCELTAEFF2 takes a value of 1, but the corresponding row on the column EV is zero.

Now, I would like to have for each respondent, INTERTOT, only one line, contaning all information that are now spread on 20 rows.

The file that I have is very big and that's why I am showing you only a part.

I would like to estimate a hybrid choice model and perform the calculation of the willingness-to-pay trough the delta method, but the very first issue is related to have the data in the right format.

The code I am trying is the following:

```
prova_reshape.wide = reshape(data = "prova_reshape", idvar = "INTERTOT", direction = "wide" )
```

but, of course, I get the following error message:

> Error in data[, timevar] : numero di dimensioni errato

because I did not specified `timevar`. Well I did not, because I did not know what to put in it. Moreover, I am not sure that specifying `idvar = "INTERTOT"` is enough.

I had a look at different sources on the web, such as the [following](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-reshape-my-data-in-r/) and [this](https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Reshape101R.pdf).

I think I could be close, but I am not sure on how to proceed.

I would be very helpful if anyone could help me.

Marco

Here an excerpt of my dataset:

```
structure(list(QI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CSET = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), INTERTOT = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L), NSCELTA = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), SCELTAEFF2 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), MARCA = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L), EV = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L
), PREZZO = c(25000L, 30000L, 25000L, 20000L, 30000L, 25000L, 
20000L, 15000L, 25000L, 15000L, 30000L, 20000L, 20000L, 25000L, 
35000L, 30000L, 20000L, 15000L, 35000L, 20000L), AUTONOMIA = c(150L, 
1200L, 150L, 800L, 150L, 400L, 350L, 400L, 250L, 400L, 350L, 
1200L, 150L, 800L, 350L, 800L, 250L, 1200L, 250L, 400L), AUTONOMIA_EV = c(150L, 
0L, 150L, 0L, 150L, 0L, 350L, 0L, 250L, 0L, 350L, 0L, 150L, 0L, 
350L, 0L, 250L, 0L, 250L, 0L), AUTONOMIA_ICEV = c(0L, 1200L, 
0L, 800L, 0L, 400L, 0L, 400L, 0L, 400L, 0L, 1200L, 0L, 800L, 
0L, 800L, 0L, 1200L, 0L, 400L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: It's better to share some usable data rather than images, if you can, edit your question, adding the output of  `dput(head(prova_reshape,20))` (it's going to put something like `structure(... `, copy it, and paste it in the question editing it).

Comment: Dear @s_t, dear Ronak Shah, thank you very much. I provided here the data for the sake of replicability.

Comment: So the result you'd like to have is a dataset with only one line for each INTERTOT, and 200 columns (10 columns by 20 rows) of other columns?

Comment: Dear @s_t, I made a mistake, I would like a dataset with only one line for each NSCELTA. I do strongly apologise for the mistake. I reviewed page 11 of the [link](http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/files/Apollo.pdf). Also checked the file in [link] (http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/files/apollo_modeChoiceData.csv) I would like my file in the same way as the one reported in these examples [link](http://www.apollochoicemodelling.com/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the data as example you posted but, if I've understood well, here what you need, all in base R. In case, it can be modified:

```
# add the timevar you need for reshape:
dats$timev <- with(dats, ave(rep(1, nrow(dats)),  CHOICE_SET, FUN = seq_along))

# now you can reshape it:
dats_w <- reshape(dats, idvar = " CHOICE_SET", timevar = "timev", direction = "wide")

# choose the column you need
dats_w <- dats_w[,c(2,1,3,4,10,6,12,7,13)]

# last add the correct column names
   colnames(dats_w) <- c('INTERVIEW','CHOICE_SET','CHOICE','BRAND_EV','BRAND_ICEV','PRICE_EV','PRICE_ICEV','RANGE_EV',' RANGE_ICEV')

dats_w
   INTERVIEW CHOICE_SET CHOICE BRAND_EV BRAND_ICEV PRICE_EV PRICE_ICEV RANGE_EV  RANGE_ICEV
1        111          1      0        4          1    25000      30000      150        1200
3        111          2      1        1          2    25000      20000      150         800
5        111          3      1        1          4    30000      25000      150         400
7        111          4      0        4          2    20000      15000      350         400
9        111          5      1        2          3    25000      15000      250         400
11       111          6      1        1          2    30000      20000      350        1200
13       111          7      0        3          1    20000      25000      150         800
15       111          8      1        2          3    35000      30000      350         800
17       111          9      0        2          4    20000      15000      250        1200
19       111         10      1        3          1    35000      20000      250         400
```

---

With data:

```
dats <- structure(list(INTERVIEW = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L), CHOICE_SET = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), CHOICE = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), BRAND = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L), EV_DUMMY = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L), PRICE = c(25000L, 30000L, 25000L, 20000L, 30000L, 25000L, 
20000L, 15000L, 25000L, 15000L, 30000L, 20000L, 20000L, 25000L, 
35000L, 30000L, 20000L, 15000L, 35000L, 20000L), RANGE = c(150L, 
1200L, 150L, 800L, 150L, 400L, 350L, 400L, 250L, 400L, 350L, 
1200L, 150L, 800L, 350L, 800L, 250L, 1200L, 250L, 400L), timev = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `structure(list(INTERVIEW = 111L, CHOICE_SET = 1L, CHOICE = 0L, 
    BRAND_EV = 4L, BRAND_ICEV = 1L, PRICE_EV = 25000L, PRICE_ICEV = 30000L, 
    RANGE_EV = 150L, RANGE_ICEV = 1200L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Dear @s_t, thank you very much. I provided in the abovereported comment the example that represents how I would like my new data to be reported.

Comment: @MarcoGiansoldati see the edit, you've only to choose the correct columns and rename them.

Comment: Dear @s_t, I will try and get back to you in the next few minutes.

Comment: Dear s_t, you are my hero. It works. Now, I have to try to do it on the whole dataset. Do you mind if I try and get back to you if I have problems?

Comment: Sure, definitely, how can mark it as correct? Super thanks. I am trying now on my database. I am not not sure how to deal with socio-economic variables, which do not vary across choices. Should I select the columns which end with 1 and those that end with a 2. Maybe I should put my data down here to show you.

Comment: My concern is on how to apply the code to the whole database. In its long format it has 4000 observations of 38 variables (there are 200 survey respondents, each one replying to 10 questions). I thus end up with 10 observations of 14801 variables. At this point I am in doubt on how to proceed to have the data for all the respondents. In other words, I am able to check the column numbers for the variables which end up with the suffix .1 and .2, which refer to EV and ICEV, but I am not sure how to proceed further for the variables such as age, gender, income which are not alternative specific.

Comment: It depends on what you've to do. If the analysis is about respondents, you'd have (I suppose) each line a respondent, so a 200*n dataset. In other words, you've to clarify which are the questions you'd like to answer with your data, then clean-reshape them, last the analysis. In your question it's not clear what you want, and it's ok you've not asked, because SO it's only a site of helping for code and related errors or issues.

Comment: Dear @s_t, I managed to do in excel, but I would like to have in R what I manually did in excel. Basically, I would like one line a choice, so 10 (number of choice sets) times 200 which is the number of respondents, for a total of 2000 rows. I dot have enough space to show you here with the command `dput(head(database,20))`.